# Is it possible to run more than one rabbitmq instance on one machine?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to build a RabbitMQ cluster in my dev machine (windows).
reason is that I would like to test and study it.

Is it possible to run more than one rabbitmq instance on one machine?
I am guessing I need to:

1. Change the listening port
2. Change the appdata folder (C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming)
3. Change the ui plugin port so I can view all instances.
4. Remove the service and run from cli

Has anyone tried it? 
Is there a known guide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This thread](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Multiple-nodes-on-single-box-tp3478p3480.html) appears to detail what you need. From the thread responses (scroll down):

> The following settings are necessary to separate the node runtimes
> completely, while allowing them to share the installed code base.
>
> RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE          /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq
>
> RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE          /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
>
> RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE             /var/log/rabbitmq
>
> RABBITMQ_ENABLED_PLUGINS_FILE /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins

Comment: Thanks. The following three were enough to do the Job - RABBITMQ_NODENAME, RABBITMQ_BASE, RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT

Comment: I'm not sure how it fits with rabbitmq clusters, but another option is to use docker. Bring up multiple docker containers and bind them to different ports on the local host.

Answer (score 8):

Now the official RabbitMQ documentation contains a section **"A Cluster on a Single Machine"**, which describes how to run multiple Rabbit nodes on a single machine.

See https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#single-machine

Answer (score 3):

You can run multiple RabbitMQ instances on 1 machine without clustering. You just need to change the ports and the node name in rabbitmq-defaults, rabbitmq-env and config files.

**For Linux:**

1. Make sure you have Erlang installed, then download the latest version for Generic Unix and extract it.
2. Go to rabbit installation folder(the folder you just extracted)/sbin -> open the rabbitmq-defaults file and change SYS_PREFIX=${RABBITMQ_HOME} to create the default folder somewhere else, you should set the path to the extracted folder, for ex. /home/YOUR-USERNAME/rabbit_server-msg(this is my extracted folder).
3. Change the node name. Open the rabbitmq-env file -> find NODENAME=rabbit@${HOSTNAME} and change the name rabbit (ex. rabbitMSG@${HOSTNAME}). In the same file locate and change DEFAULT_NODE_PORT, by default it’s set to 5672. The default clustering port is set by  ${DEFAULT_NODE_PORT} + 20000. So if you set the default node port to 5673, the clustering port will be 25673.
4. Install the Management Plugin. Navigate to rabbitmq-server/sbin and run “./rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management”
5. The AMQP and HTTP ports need to be chnaged in the config file. Copy the file rabbitmq.config.example and paste it in the rabbit_server-msg(again this is my extracted forlder)/etc(this is the default folder created by RabbitMQ from step 1)/rabbitmq folder, rename the file to just rabbitmq.config. If you can’t find the file rabbitmq.config.example in the rabbit folder create a file named rabbitmq.config and copy the code from their GitHub.
6. Open the config file and uncomment the following lines:

– {tcp_listeners, [5672]} and change the port number (It is recommended to set the same number as the DEFAULT_NODE_PORT in rabbitmq-env for example 5673).

– {listener, [{port,     12345} and change the port number (This is for the management plugin).

NOTE: Be careful with the commas and brackets. Remove the comma after {tcp_listeners, [5672]}. Also after {listener, [{port,     12345} close the brackets like so ]}. Otherwise when you try to run ./rabbitmq-server it will show errors (It will show you on which line in the config file you have an error so you can fix it).

Now start up the server and log in the manager. Check the Listening ports under Ports and contexts to see if you made the changes. Do this for the other servers and you will be able to run as many servers as you want on 1 machine all with different listening ports. To start the RabbitMQ server automatically when you log in use the Startup Application program.

**For Windows:**

Setting up RabbitMQ for Windows is preatty much the same as on Linux.

1. Make sure you have Erlang installed, then download the latest version for Windows and extract it.
2. Go to rabbit(the folder you just extracted)/sbin -> open the rabbitmq-defaults.bat file and change RABBITMQ_BASE to create the default folder somewhere else, you should set the path to the extracted folder, for ex. C:/rabbit_server-msg(this is my extracted folder).
3. Change the node name. Open the rabbitmq-env.bat file -> find RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@!HOSTNAME! and change the name rabbit (ex. rabbitMSG@!HOSTNAME!). In the same file locate and change RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT, by default it’s set to 5672. To change the default clustering port locate and change RABBITMQ_DIST_PORT, by default it’s set to 25672.
4. Install the Management Plugin. Navigate to rabbit-server/sbin and run “rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management”.
5. The AMQP and HTTP ports need to be chnaged in the config file. Create a file named rabbitmq.config and copy the code from their GitHub. Put the file in your installation folder/RabbitMQ (ex. my config is in C:/rabbit_server-msg/RabbitMQ). Also in the rabbitmq-defaults.bat file check CONFIG_FILE it should be set to CONFIG_FILE=!RABBITMQ_BASE!\rabbitmq.
6. Open the config file and uncomment the following lines:

– {tcp_listeners, [5672]} and change the port number (It is recommended to set the same number as the RABBITMQ_NODE_PORTin rabbitmq-env for example 5673).

– {listener, [{port,     12345} and change the port number (This is for the management plugin).

NOTE: Be careful with the commas and brackets. Remove the comma after {tcp_listeners, [5672]}. Also after {listener, [{port,     12345} close the brackets like so ]}. Otherwise when you try to run rabbitmq-server.bat it will show errors (It will show you on which line in the config file you have an error so you can fix it).

Now start up the server and log in the manager. Check the Listening ports under Ports and contexts to see if you made the changes. Do this for the other servers and you will be able to run as many servers as you want on 1 machine all with different listening ports.

**Source:** https://lazareski.com/multiple-rabbitmq-instances-on-1-machine/

Answer (score 1):

One approach that I took when testing out clustering on my dev machine was to fire up several VMs. I had several for Rabbit and one for HAProxy.

While you can, as per one of the other answers, run multiple instances on a single OS instance, the multiple VM approach allowed me to mimic the intended production environment more closely.

NB. I have chosen to interpret your 'one machine' as meaning a physical machine for the purpose of this answer. If your meaning was 'virtual' then I defer to the other answer posted against this question which details how to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks. I did mean a physical machine. Eventually I did the following 1. I have created three folders 2. edit the run script to update different ports 3. edited the config file to to update different ports  for the ui plugin. Did the job.

Comment: Don't forget, you'll still need some form of load balancer to broker requests between the instances if you want to test out the cluster in action.

Comment: Is this what HAProxy is for?

Comment: Yep. HAProxy is a load balancing proxy. If you are going to cluster Rabbit then you need to only expose a single endpoint as you won't know which one might fail. HAProxy takes care of proxying requests to live members of the cluster as it is able to determine whether a node is down or not. See: http://haproxy.1wt.eu/