# RabbitMQ: Installing multiple rabbit MQ servers in one system

Tags: linux, rabbitmq

Is it possible to install multiple rabbitmq-server in one system?

I have one linux VM, where, I have 2 instances of same application, running on 2 different ports. Now, this application, uses, rabbit MQ. 
So, I need 2 separate instance of rabbit MQ, for these 2 applications.

Therefore, how to manage this scenario?

Comment: i am not sure about the answer, but may i suggest that you use different Q or Q-naming for each application of the 2?

Comment: yup!.. that i can do. But personally speaking, I'm not interested on that approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run more than one rabbitmq instance on one machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453910/is-it-possible-to-run-more-than-one-rabbitmq-instance-on-one-machine)