# Unable to start second rabbitmq node on single Windows host

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to run two `rabbitmq` nodes on a single windows host. My end goal is to run two rabbitmq services.
currently, I have the following commands for the second node in `rabbitmq-env-conf.bat` :

```
set RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.conf
set RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit2@hostname
set RABBITMQ_DIST_PORT=5673
set RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS="-rabbitmq_management listener [{port,15673}]"
```

Running `.\rabbitmq-server.bat start` produces the following error :

```
 . . .
Starting broker...Logger - error: {removed_failing_handler,rabbit_log}

BOOT FAILED
===========
Error during startup: {error,
                       {rabbitmq_management,
                        {bad_return,
                         {{rabbit_mgmt_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                          {'EXIT',
                           {{could_not_start_listener,
                             [{cowboy_opts,[{sendfile,false}]},{port,15672}],
                             {shutdown,
                              {failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,
                               {listen_error,
                                {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},15672},
                                eaddrinuse}}}},
 . . .
```

From the log :

```
 Application rabbitmq_management exited with reason: {{could_not_start_listener,[{cowboy_opts,[{sendfile,false}]},{port,15672}],{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,{listen_error,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},15672},eaddrinuse}}}},{gen_server,call,[rabbit_web_dispatch_registry,{add,rabbitmq_management_tcp,[{cowboy_opts,[{sendfile,false}]},{port,15672}],#Fun<rabbit_web_dispatch.0.73002970>,[{'_',[],[{[],[],rabbit_mgmt_wm_static,{priv_file,rabbitmq_management,"www/index.html"}},{[<<"api">>,<<"overview">>],[],rabbit_mgmt_wm_overview,...},...]}],...},...]}}
```

It looks like I am unable to setup the rabbitmq management port successfully despite suppling starting args.
15672 is the first rabbitmq's management port number and I am not sure why this number is being picked up.
Some troubleshooting pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21453973/751579) help?  It suggests that `RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT` is the key.  But the answer is several years old - things may have changed and YMMV.

Comment: thanks davidbak! , unfortunately that did not help and yeah as you pointed out it is things have changed.